# After Artifactory upgrade to 5.10.2, remote repo connections fail with Proxy Error 407

Tags: artifactory, http-proxy

We have updated our ***Artifactory*** from 5.2.0 to ***5.10.2***.
Since that, all remote repository test connection failed with ***Proxy error 407***.

The proxy is correctly set in Admin section, the Proxy has been set for all repo.
login/password are valid.

There's no log error except this one :

```
20180419151212|30|REQUEST|172.22.50.135|usertst|POST|/ui/admin/repositories/testremote|HTTP/1.1|400|1610
```

Unfortunately I can't bypass the proxy.

It used to work so I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore since the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a bug that has been reported](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-16487). You may want to vote & watch the JIRA for updates.